# Receiving neither grouped nor aggregated error with cte syntax in Bigquery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to generate a count of NFL players by college from a dataset in BigQuery (i.e. Florida State-15, Iowa State-10, etc.) via the following:

```
With cte_Players as (
SELECT displayName AS Player, 
collegeName AS College 
FROM NFL.Players)
SELECT cte_players.College, 
COUNT(cte_Players.Player)
FROM cte_Players
```

When I do this I end up getting this error: SELECT list expression references cte_Players.College which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:8] How might I solve this?

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY when aggregating.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the grouping part, since you have aggregations, it is a must.

I have a little tweak though:

```
WITH cte_Players AS (
  SELECT displayName AS Player, 
         collegeName AS College 
  FROM NFL.Players
)
SELECT College, 
       COUNT(Player) AS PlayerCount
FROM cte_Players
GROUP BY College
ORDER BY PlayerCount DESC;
```

This will count and sort players per college.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `GROUP BY` to your query.

Your query should look like this:

```
With cte_Players as (
SELECT displayName AS Player, 
collegeName AS College 
FROM NFL.Players)
SELECT cte_players.College, 
COUNT(cte_Players.Player)
FROM cte_Players
GROUP BY College --added code
```